# Pasar parametro a una sentencia mysql en C# y ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, asp, vb

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 MySqlCommand operacion = new MySqlCommand("select destino_enlace from 
 tutoriales where nombre_pantalla='Cabecera'", conexion);
```

Dicho codigo luego me devuelve una URL. Bien, lo que quería hacer es que en vez de que nombre_pantalla sea siempre cabecera,  como podría hacer para pasarle un parametro que sea capaz de devolver la URL correcta para no repetir la misma sentencia ya que hay distintas nombre_pantalla guardadas en la base de datos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Edito este post ya que estuve un tiempo dejando de lado este tema:

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
  string cadConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString;
MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString);
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("select destino_enlace from tutoriales where nombre_pantalla = @parametro", conexion);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametro", "Cabecera");
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametro", "Inicio");
    //lector = comando.ExecuteReader();
    conexion.Open();
    MySqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader();

    if (lector.Read())
    {

        HyperCabecera.NavigateUrl = lector.GetString("destino_enlace");
        HyperCabecera.Target = "_blank";
    }
    lector.Close();
    conexion.Close();
```

Quisiera hacer de alguna forma (sin repetir la consulta SQL), que lea igual que lee cuando el parametro es cabecera, que lea tambien cuando es inicio y abra el enlace correspondiente. Sería posible hacerlo sinn hacer la consulta a la tabla de nuevo?

```
      while (lector.Read())
    {

         if (var1=="Cabecera")
        {
            HyperCabecera.NavigateUrl = lector.GetString("destino_enlace");
            HyperCabecera.Target = "_blank";
        }

        if (var2 == "Inicio")
        {
            HyperInici.NavigateUrl = lector.GetString("destino_enlace");
            HyperInici.Target = "_blank";
        }


    }
```

Comment: tendrias que declarar variables con los nombres de las secciones y cambiar ese if por un while(lector.Read()) dentro poner in if(var1 =="Cabecera"), este comentario es segun lo que pude entender de tu comentario, o intenta explicarlo mejor

Comment: Así como he puesto en el post de arriba no me funciona. Me muestra el primer valor.

Comment: Lo he solucionado. Era tal cual me indicabas. He sacado con un lector.GetString("nombre_pantalla") todas las secciones y las he comparado. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer lo que buscas, debes usar la propiedad [`Parameters`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm) del objeto [`MySqlCommand`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand.htm).

La clase [`MySqlParameterCollection`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection.htm) (que es el tipo de la propiedad [`Parameters`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm)) posee varios métodos para llegar a lo que buscas, en nuestro caso, vamos a usar [`AddWithValue`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection_AddWithValue.htm).

Su uso es muy sencillo, en tu query, deberás definir el nombre de tu parámetro, para el ejemplo, usaré el nombre `@parametro`, por ende, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
MySqlCommand operacion = new MySqlCommand("select destino_enlace from 
tutoriales where nombre_pantalla=@parametro", conexion);
```

Ahora, añadiremos el parámetro con el método que mencioné antes:

```
operacion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametro", "Cabecera");
```

Dónde, el primer parámetro, representa el nombre del parámetro, y el segundo su valor.

De esta manera, se generaría la misma query de tu ejemplo, pero parametrizada.

Comment: Eso lo he hecho, pero solo me deja asignar un valor a cada parámetro. Como podría asignarle distintos valores (todos los nombres de las secciones)?